# Besides Gun Runners, where can I buy missiles?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Where can I buy ammo besides Gun Runners? I'm looking for missiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For high end weaponry and ammunition, you have a few good options. The Gun Runners robot is one, [Sergeant Contreras](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Contreras) at Camp McCarran is another. The [Great Khan Armorer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Khan_armorer), [Mick](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mick_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)), [Quartermaster Bardon](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bardon), [Knight Torres](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Torres), and the unnamed [Arms Merchant](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arms_Merchant) will tend to carry high level weapons rather frequently once you're of the appropriate level as well.

You'll also *almost always* find a large supply of Missiles and other heavy explosive ordnance being sold by [the Boomer Munitions Manager](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Boomer_Munitions_Manager) over at Nellis AFB, along with tons of Missiles lying around on the ground for you to steal, if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Contreras](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dealing_with_Contreras) at the supply shack in Camp McCarran. He sells mostly weapons/ammo. The link I put links to his quests, but that's the guy in case you don't know where he is.

Answer (score 1):

Contreras is the best supply of 12.7mm ammo, and there is an unnamed arms merchant at the 188 that also has a great stock of ammo.